# How do I break out of a While True Loop and Go back to the Loop

Tags: python, loops, python-requests, break

So each request it sends keeps printing

```
{"success":false,"code":7,"message":"Ad creation cooldown has not elapsed"}
```

and everytime it prints this I want it to break the loop and wait for 15 seconds then do the loop again.
My Code:

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

cookies = dict(_RoliData='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxLCJwbGF5ZXJfZGF0YSI6eyJuYW1lIjoiNzZfNzciLCJpZCI6MTUxMjExNDM0fSwiaWF0IjoxNTk5NzIyMjM4LCJleHAiOjE2MDc0OTgyOTh9.qVFHIhsXKgQIZvLvJzH0WFZbcsgZE5Ou_H_0laIbFk4', _RoliVerification= 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxLCJwbGF5ZXJfZGF0YSI6eyJuYW1lIjoiNzZfNzciLCJpZCI6MTUxMjExNDM0fSwiaWF0IjoxNTk5NzIyMjM4LCJleHAiOjE2MDc0OTgyOTh9.WtCyuWnKnIzA7PMUyCBqihXwaqfunZQkiMQd1n6s6-Q')

payload = json.dumps({"player_id":151211434,"offer_item_ids":[1241224444,20573078,187483689,24826811],"request_item_ids":[144506778,96095042,1533893,1051578],"request_tags":[]})

while True:
    g = requests.post('https://www.rolimons.com/tradeapi/create', headers=headers, data=payload, cookies=cookies)
    print(g.text)
```

Comment: `break` will terminate a loop.  `time.sleep(15)` will pause for 15 seconds.

Comment: It seems kind of pointless to post identical requests over and over...

Comment: The reason is each 20 minutes my request will work

Comment: There's no need to break the loop. Do the rest of your calculations inside the loop, then `sleep` for 20 minutes.

Comment: Yes, but I want it to print for example print("Cooldown 20 minutes") so the user that uses my program knows that you need to wait 20 minutes for each request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments. Use `time.sleep(t)` to stop for t seconds.
You could use a flag to exit the loop when it's ready and why not, to check if the `status_code` was the expected too.

```py
response_not = {"success":False,"code":7,"message":"Ad creation cooldown has not elapsed"}
exit = False
while not exit:
    g = requests.post(
          'https://www.rolimons.com/tradeapi/create',
          headers=headers,
          data=payload,
          cookies=cookies
        )
    if g.status_code == 200:
        if g.json() == response_not:
            time.sleep(15)
        else:
            exit = True
    else:
        print(f"Warn: Status code was {g.status_code}")
        exit = True
```